# Log4net have a FileAppender with date pattern

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration

I am trying to do something that I thought was simple.

To have a FileAppender in log4net with a date in the filename.

Before you rush to answer this, I need to make clear that I don't need a RollingFileAppender, because I know it's possible with that one.
I want to produce 1 log file every time I run my console app. So I don't need a rolling file appender, just 1 file each time, with a timestamp on it.

This is where it gets tricky because this configuration:

```
<log4net>
    <root>
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="MyFileAppender" />
    </root>
    <appender name="MyFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
        <file value="logs\" />
        <datePattern value="dd.MM.yyyy'.log'" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date %level %logger - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
</log4net>
```

Gives this error:

```
log4net:ERROR XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Cannot find Property [datePattern] to se
t object on [log4net.Appender.FileAppender]
```

It works if I don't have a pattern and just have a static file that keeps getting overriden each time the app.

So is this not possible with a file appender? 
I am using version 1.2.15.0.

Answer (score 3):

that did it:

```
<appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
    <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="logs\App-%date{yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss}.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%2thread] %-5level - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```